# Set <a href> name to open a specific video when supplying a link

Tags: jquery, html, lightbox

On my webpage, I have a link to a video. The link itself works fine, if I want the user to navigate away to the video and watch it, but I am wanting it to pop up in a lightbox for viewing on-click, instead.

An example of this working can be found at [this link](http://continentalgold.com/English/investors/media-center/video-gallery/default.aspx#aniVid).

Comment: Could you clarify further what you mean by "act like someone clicked the video itself," please?

Comment: So I go to this link: http://continentalgold.com/English/investors/media-center/video-gallery/default.aspx#aniVid and the animation video pops up in the lightbox, just as it does when you click on it.

Comment: What is the file type of the video?

Answer (score 1):

The example you provided at that link is using `fancybox` (specifically, version 1.3.4), which you can find at http://fancybox.net/. The magic behind it is not in the `name` tag, but in the `class` which is being applied to the `a`.

Specifically, the `a` tag is written as follows:

```
<a href="http://example.com/video/12345678" class="fancyboxiframe">link text</a>
```

And the following script, when run, creates the effect I think you're looking for:

```
$('a.fancyboxiframe ,.Video a[href*="vimeo"]').fancybox({
    'type':   'iframe',
    'height':  464, 
    'width' :  853
});
```

This activates the `fancybox` jQuery plugin, which tells the browser that what you want to do when you click on the link is to pop it up in an `iframe`-based lightbox.

According to the API:

> > 'type': Forces content type. Can be set to 'image', 'ajax', 'iframe', 'swf' or 'inline'

Try taking a look at the documentation for the plugin on the site. It's pretty easy to use, and should give you what you're looking for, when also armed with the above script as an example.

Comment: @user2221160 If you don't want to use Fancybox specifically there will be a number of alternative lightbox solutions available, with varying features and complexity. Simply search for "video lightbox".